# How can I have some namespaces available only in a development build?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am trying to setup my Zend Framework project with some development helper code. But I want the use of that code in our testing environment to throw errors (would also throw errors in production, but they should all be dealt with in testing).

The strategy I'm looking at is putting all the development helper code in a particular namespace in Zend that isn't included in the Testing or Production builds.

The namespace is **Dev_**

Here is how I'm trying to do this in the application.ini:

```
[production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 0
phpSettings.display_errors = 0
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"
appnamespace = "Application"
resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 0
autoloaderNamespaces[] = "Events_"

[staging : production]

[testing : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1

[development : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1
autoloaderNamespaces[] = "Dev_"
```

The problem is that like this, the application seems to ignore the "Events_" namespace.  I've tried removing `autoloaderNamespaces[] = "Dev_"` and it was then recognizing "Events_" again.

My understanding is that I should be able to add any number of custom namespaces this way. How can I get this setup to ignore the **Dev_** namespace outside of Development builds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd think it may be possible to do `autoloaderNamespaces.events = "Events_` and it won't be rewritten later. `autoloaderNamespaces.dev = "Dev_"` - the [] are just convenience IMO

Comment: Yes, so with the [] it has to be duplicated, but with the dot notation `.dev .event` I can have it combined across Production and Development.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding both namespaces to the development block:

```
[development : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1
autoloaderNamespaces[] = "Events_"
autoloaderNamespaces[] = "Dev_"
```

At the moment you are overriding the namespace being set in production.

Comment: Yep, I was figuring if it was additive inside of one, it would be additive across multiples. Thanks.